# JavaScript If statement works, but Else doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, multiple-select

When I run this code, the if statement under onClick evaluates when view.checked == true, but the else does not evaluate when view.checked == false. The alert shows that view.checked seems to be working properly. No idea what's going on. I'm using these two plugins:

https://datatables.net/ with fnFilter plugin

and

http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select

As a side note, also trying to figure out why my .join() method adds spaces.

```
var checked = [];
var checkedreg = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
    rtable = $('#ropes').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/ropes.txt",
        "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
        "columns": [
            { "data": "brand" },
            { "data": "model" },
            { "data": "length" },
            { "data": "dia" },
            { "data": "price" },
            { "data": "drytreat" },
            { "data": "midmark" },
            { "data": "bipat" },
            { "data": "falls" },
        ],
    });
    $('select').multipleSelect({
       onClick: function(view) {
        checkedreg = ''; 
        alert(view.checked);
        if (view.checked) { //if checkbox is checked
                checked.push(view.label); //add value of checkbox to "checked" array (ex. "Petzl")
            } 
            else {
                checked.splice(array.indexOf(view.label), 1); //if checkbox is not checked, remove value from array
                alert(checked); //test
            }
            checkedreg = checked.join("|"); //create regex of values ("Petzl| Mammut| Edelweiss)"
            checkedreg = checkedreg.replace(/\s+/g, ''); //for some reason it adds spaces so i have to remove them
            alert(checkedreg); //test
            alert(checked); //test
            rtable.fnFilter(checkedreg, 0, true); //filters a column based on a regex and column index
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: What does alert(view.checked); say? Also, what does your JavaScritp console say?

Comment: Still trying to identify the root problem. I can tell you though, you've got an extra brace `}` near the bottom of the `$('select').multipleSelect({...` code. You're also missing the closing semicolon `;` on the end of that same code block.

Comment: you probably need to explicitly set a check what view.checked equals when its true and not when its false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `checked.splice(array.indexOf(view.label), 1);` with `checked.splice(checked.indexOf(view.label), 1);` and try